# fast comparison a list with itself

Tags: performance, comparison

I have a list giant list (100k entries) in my database. Each entry contains a id, text and a date.

I created a function to compare two text as possible. How it looks like is not necessary right now.

Is there a "good" way to remove "duplicates" (as possible) from the list by text?
Currently I'm looping through the list twice and compare each entry with each entry, except itself by id.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is when you insert a row in the table... you can include the unique constraint.

Postgresql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
 id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 txt VARCHAR (50),
 dt timestamp,
 UNIQUE(txt)
);

Oracle
CREATE TABLE table1 
( id numeric(10) NOT NULL,
  txt varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  date timestamp,
  CONSTRAINT txt_unique UNIQUE (txt)
);

Comment: No it is not. I already have the content in the database and now I want to remove all duplicates by certain criteria, which my function decides. I know that I have to loop through it, but maybe there is a much faster way than compare 100k^2 entries.